# Mercurial Push/Pull verbose output

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is it possible for a verbose output of what exactly is happening when I push/pull the repositories? Currently, I have a large repository that I am pushing to the server, and after about 15 min. or so, it gives me an error, but does not tell me what it was doing during those 15 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have unselected the previous answer due to additional info. For anybody who comes across this problem, you may be using TortoiseHg 1.1.7 from [HERE](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). Try the newer version from [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/downloads). As far as I can tell, this version is much better, cleaner GUI, more feature-filled interface and has verbose output that I wanted, and overall is definitely worth the switch. The version is 1.9. I am not sure if it is a continuation of the original TortoiseHg or a completely new project altogether.

Comment: You have found the Qt port of TortoiseHg. The first version of TortoiseHg used GTK as the graphics toolkit, but some months ago they began rewriting the application to use Qt instead. This gives better cross platform compatibility.

Comment: @Samaursa I still don't see where the verbose output option is or where to find that output...

Comment: @Kohanz: The output log (click on the log icon) gives you all the information. Not sure whether it is verbose or not but it is good enough for my needs so far.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the `-v` verbose parameter? As in;

```
hg pull -v
hg push -v
```

Comment: My apologies for not pointing out that I am using TortoiseHg, is there such an option in there as well?

Comment: Sorry I never used TortoiseHG, someone else might help if it has a verbose option.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will use the command line for this and hope that they will add this in a later release